# Как в вордпресс убрать основное окно контента?

Tags: wordpress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Делаю шаблон с произвольными полями, соответственно главное контентное окно не нужно, можно ли его убрать с помощью functions.php?  и как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте этот код в functions.php

```
function hide_editor() {
    remove_post_type_support('page', 'editor');
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'hide_editor' );
```